# Group list of 4-strings into list of pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following list of strings:

```
['word1 word2 word3 word4', 'word5 word6 word7 word8']
```

(I have shown only two strings, but there can be many.)
I want to create new list which should look like this:

```
['word1 word2', 'word3 word4', 'word5 word6', 'word7 word8']
```

I tried following:

```
lines = ['word1 word2 word3 word4', 'word5 word6 word7 word8']
[[word1 + ' ' + word2, word3 + ' ' + word4] for line in lines for word1, word2, word3, word4 in line.split()]
```

But it gives following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

How do I do this in most pythonic way?

Comment: yeah, thats mistake, fixed ... its should be `lines = ['word1 word2 word3 word4', 'word5 word6 word7 word8']`

Answer (score 2):

With short regex matching:

```
import re

lst = ['word1 word2 word3 word4', 'word5 word6 word7 word8']
res = [pair for words in lst for pair in re.findall(r'\S+ \S+', words)]
```

- `\S+ \S+` - matches 2 consecutive "*words*"

---

```
['word1 word2', 'word3 word4', 'word5 word6', 'word7 word8']
```

Comment: Might make sense to just use `\S+` instead of `\w+`; the latter is whitelisting alphanumeric+underscores only (so a word like `it's` wouldn't match), while the former is saying "any run of non-whitespace counts as a word". Also, if performance counts, precompiling the regex and using the method of the precompiled regex would help (`re` does cache compiled regex for the recently used patterns, but repeatedly rechecking the cache is itself an unnecessary expense; admittedly, it's a microoptimization at this point). Up-voted regardless.

Comment: For the record, the "pushes all the work to the C layer" version of this solution would be `res = list(chain.from_iterable(map(re.compile(r'\S+ \S+').findall, lst)))` (with a `from itertools import chain` at the top of the script). This assumes microoptimizations are in fact important (your solution that spells it out more clearly is almost certainly better most of the time).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I'm know about compiled pattern but omitted it for such a simple case

Comment: @ShadowRanger, keeping all in generator will surely save space, but not and not in all cases give speed advantage (when `list(<gen>)`) over list comprehension. (though I also like generators)

Comment: Nitpick: It's an iterator, not a generator. Generators (Python-level generator expressions, that look like listcomps with parens, or generator functions, that look like regular functions using `yield`) do some wasted overhead when the result will be `list`ified anyway, but C-implemented iterators generally don't have that problem (they just need to be running on *enough* data to justify the slightly higher setup costs); there's no jumping back and forth between C and Python level code like actual generators involve.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yes, I misspoke, ... iterators. Testing on `['word1 word2 word3 word4', 'word5 word6 word7 word8'] * 10_000` (for golfing) ?

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic doesn't mean "fewer lines". This is easily done with a simple for loop:

```
result = []
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    result.append(' '.join(words[:2]))
    result.append(' '.join(words[2:]))
```

Which gives your desired result:

```
['word1 word2', 'word3 word4', 'word5 word6', 'word7 word8']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY1LCgMhDED3niI7FYpQpz@EnmRwMTCWWiSKWkpPbyeZCzSLF5K8JOXbnxmnMVLE0OAOs/zkuh6BaJkT8yQPwKMzlxfmlXmTXtTQ3qnTvhePXIHOQUTOzQnYglT6QC3TSopdaR7su2YpJeCqJEjzyhEV@7OzXv@hWUeaKDViV7upx/gB)

If you want to make this more general for strings with more words, you can write a function that will yield chunks of the desired size, and use that with `str.join`:

```
def chunks(iterable, chunk_size):
    c = []
    for item in iterable:
        c.append(item)
        if len(c) == chunk_size:
            yield c
            c = []

    if c: yield c

result = []
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    for chunk in chunks(words, 2):
        result.append(' '.join(chunk))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLjsIwDLznK3xLI1WVFtiHkPolK4QgdYV3QxolQQh@vtROKbs@jBJ7xvY43PJp8OtxdOQxQQvf@jrE7g0YV4JrwY2uQUrv8v0Q/BT80julOuzBni7@N1WUMR6ODuuS2Ce6o9kqmMLyhJ08@yHCxDwDeXgqCkmIzSEE9B03O5slTT049JU10LZ/ur90HDdC14H9l5sHq7mJ3S4sFTFdXC51XoovwUvJRUpndsnH4VSTgqNcmcWErMGC2b6Qa1iZ11ZlxNOSBt38DDTZYIExSoVIPleFZcbxAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Modified @jsbueno's ealier answer which was slightly incorrect:

```
>>> words = [item for line in lines for item in line.split()]
>>> words
['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', 'word7', 'word8']
>>> [l[i] + ' ' + l[i+1] for i in range(0, len(words), 2)]
['word1 word2', 'word3 word4', 'word5 word6', 'word7 word8']
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized solution that pushes all the per-item work to the C layer:

```
from itertools import chain

lines = ['word1 word2 word3 word4', 'word5 word6 word7 word8']
words = chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, lines))
paired = list(map('{} {}'.format, words, words))
print(paired)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3LCsIwEEX3@YrZpYVS0Pra@CUiEm1KB/JiMiBS@u2xGd2cyzD3kT48xzCUMlH0gGyJY3QZ0KdIDK/ZYFDKYbAZrnDT70jjDir3wkF40B3I6yjnSXgWXvRdVa1xaevr0qMumaezjTepyUx9Tg65A1lqW5UMkh23jMPMYtLLCsuq@ymSN5tTSv9SA4SBm1@sLeUL)

`chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, lines))` creates an iterator of the individual words. `map('{} {}'.format, words, words)` maps the same iterator twice to put them back together in pairs (`map(' '.join, zip(words, words))` would get the same effect, but with an additional intermediate product; feel free to test which is faster in practice). The `list` wrapper consumes it to produce the final result.

This beats the existing answers by avoiding all per-item work at the Python layer (no additional bytecode executed as the input grows), and avoids one of the weirdly high overhead aspects of Python (indexing and simple integer math).